# Как сделать не кликабельной определенную строку ListView?

Tags: android, listview

Разметка строки для заполнения ListView через адаптер:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="48dp"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

В адаптере по условию я определяю какую именно строчку я ищу.
Какой кусок кода необходимо прописать в это условие, чтобы данная строка ListView стала не кликабельна?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в адаптере

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return false; // тут условие по которому нужно "задисаблить"
}
```